# Zero-length error when trying to Lag xts time series?

Tags: r, xts

I have basic xts object generated using the following.

```
library(quantmod)
temp1 <- getSymbols("GOOG",src = 'yahoo',from=Sys.Date()-50,to = Sys.Date(),auto.assign=FALSE)
temp2 <- temp1$GOOG.Close
head(temp2)
           GOOG.Close
2020-05-20    1406.72
2020-05-21    1402.80
2020-05-22    1410.42
2020-05-26    1417.02
2020-05-27    1417.84
2020-05-28    1416.73
lag(temp2,1)
Error in c.xts(NA_real_, c(1406.719971, 1402.800049, 1410.420044, 1417.02002,  : 
  zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed
```

As far as I can tell temp2 is not zero length so I don't understand the error.

Similarly the diff(temp2) function does work as expected.

This seems to have started when I recently updated to R 4.0.1

I cannot find any explanation for this error considering I do have a non-zero vector.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have `dplyr` loaded, by chance? That's the only way I can replicate your error.

`dplyr` masks the `stats::lag()` generic function that ships with base R. That breaks method dispatch for all S3 classes that define a `lag()` method. So that means `lag()` may or may not work for those classes.

```r
R> head(lag(temp2, 1))
           GOOG.Close
2020-05-26         NA
2020-05-27    1417.02
2020-05-28    1417.84
2020-05-29    1416.73
2020-06-01    1428.92
2020-06-02    1431.82
R> suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))
R> head(lag(temp2, 1))
Error in c.xts(NA_real_, c(1417.02002, 1417.839966, 1416.72998, 1428.920044,  : 
  zero-length vectors with non-zero-length index are not allowed
```

So you either need to: 1) not load dplyr, or 2) explicitly call `stats::lag()` everywhere you don't want to use `dplyr::lag()`.

Comment: Yes I do use dplyr and I will use the suggested workaround. Since this started with 4.x did dplyr change recently to cause this error? I have not changed anything in this part of the code in months.

Comment: @MichaelE: no, dplyr has been that way for a long time (despite several people pointing out it is very confusing and disruptive). I'm not sure what might have changed... did you always have dplyr loaded before that code is called in your script?

Comment: I think I had it for a while, but I am not sure. I will remove it to see what, if anything specifically uses it.